# How do i refresh a ListFragment list based on other fragment's method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the tipical 2-fragment display on a RSS reader app.
One fragment with the list of titles, and one fragment with the detail of the selected title.

It works perfect on mobile devices, but on tablets (and wide devices) i can not refresh the list (the cursor i mean), to mark the items as read.

Any idea about how to get it done, how to get the fragment "refreshed" or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fragment to refresh is declared in XML, you can use the FragmentManager and get the instance of it by its ID. Then you can call whatever methods you want in your 1st fragment from your 2nd fragment or host activity or wherever